# Hidden text in jQuery animation() doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

HTML:

```
<div>
    <code id="code">about</code>
    <code id="hid-code"></code>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
 }
div {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100px;
    height: 1.1em;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #91e0ee;
    margin: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
 }
#code {
    padding: 2%;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    color: #91e0ee;
    vertical-align: top;
 }
#hid-code {
    font-variant: small-caps;
    color: #91e0ee;
    display: none;
 }
```

JS:

```
// STRING TO HIDE
var hidCode = ": who is index?";

// APPEND hidCode TO #hid-code
document.getElementById('hid-code').innerHTML = hidCode;

// jQuery ANIMATION
$("div").click(function() {
    // STYLE ANIMATION
    $("div")
        .animate({ width: "20%", fontSize: "18px" }, "slow" )
        .animate({ borderLeftWidth: "5px", }, 500 );
    // HIDDEN STRING SHOWS UP
    $("hid-code").appendTo('#code').show("slow");
})
```

The string added to the variable `hidCode` should show up after the `// STYLE ANIMATION`.
I used the `display: none` to hide the string in the `hid-code` id.
Therefore, if I `append()` it to the `code` id, and use `show()`, it should work, but nothing happens. Any tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `#` in `$("hid-code")`, because you have defined it as an id. So, it has to be: `$("#hid-code")` for jQuery to find it.

Comment: np, you can find the usage of selectors in jQuery here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp